# jQuery Masonry adding extra space between two elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I am using jQuery Masonry and it is not working fine. It does not arrange elements as it should. Here are some screenshots to demonstrate the problem.

[image: Extra Space Screenshot :]

CSS code:

```
#cont {
width:100%;
height:0 auto;
min-height:670px;
padding:15px 15px;
}
#cont .item {
display:block;
width:auto;
padding:10px;
border-radius:2px 2px 2px;
background:#fff;
border:1px solid #ddd;
float:left;
margin:5px;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('#cont').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item'
}).imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('#cont').masonry('reload');
});
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?  I'm getting an extra 7px of vertical space in some places.

Answer (score -1):

Use `disply: inline-block;` for `.item` element instead of `display:block;`